# A sort of reversed cat

Tags: shell, sed, cat

I've two documents that are the result of SQL Queries.

For exemple i've my *Doc1.lst* that is :

```
    John1    0
    Julien  10
    Jules3   0
    Julie   30
```

On this Doc1.lst, I used sed to have only the name part, so *Doc2.lst* is :

```
    John1
    Julien
    Jules3
    Julie
```

I don't master enough the **sed** command to catch only the numbers, so I would like to know if there is a way to create a Doc3.lst that take the Doc1.lst and delete into it the content of Doc2.lst

It would be a sort of reversed **catenate**.
By the way, if you have the **sed** command to catch only the numbers that would be great.

Comment: why not awk if you need just numbers from Doc1.lst: awk '{ print $2 }' Doc1.lst ?

Comment: `cat Doc1.lst |awk '{print $2}' > Doc3.lst`

Comment: @Miline Possible it should be $3

Comment: `grep -wo '[0-9]\+' Doc1.lst > Doc3.lst`

Comment: $2 works for me :-)

Comment: @Costas your solution takes the numbers from names.. has same problem as the answer.

Comment: I tried $2 it gives me all the names, then $3 and it gives me nothing, but when I tried $1 it gaved me what i wanted i.e. only the numbers.

Comment: @Miline See edited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the output you want, you could either use `awk`, `cut` or `sed`. The former is preferable.

If your file `Doc1.lst` is as follow

```
John1    0
Julien  10
Jules3   0
Julie   30
```

The following `awk` command will get the output you want. Assuming field separator is a space.

`awk '{print $1}' Doc1.lst`

Using `cut`

```
cut -d' ' -f1 Doc1.lst
```

Or using `sed`. Note. `sed` is a stream editor and you don't want to use `sed` for this task. But here is the line you want anyway.

`sed 's/\([a-zA-Z]*\).*/\1/' Doc1.lst`

Answer (score 2):

`awk '{print $1}' Doc1.lst > Doc3.lst`

Comment: This is a typical useless use of `cat` If I understand the question, the OP want's the first field only. That'd be  `awk '{print $1}' Doc1.lst`  There is no need for `cat`. `awk` can read a file as well.

Comment: In my case your command work but not using {print $2} but {print $1}. Your answer gives me the names, using $1 it gives me the numbers.

Comment: @val0x00ff Updated

Comment: @Miline You now just need to substitute `$2` with `$1` and off you go!

Answer (score 1):

```
tr -s '[:space:]' \\n <infile | grep '^[0-9]'
```

...or...

```
sed '/^[0-9]/P;y| |\n|;D' <infile
```

...or probably just...

```
sed 's/.* //' <infile
```

...though for the last one you might want to do `s/ *$//` first in case there are trailing blanks.

More generally you can number a group with `sed`...

```
sed 's/ *[^ ]\{1,\} *//' <infile
```

...written like that would strip from a line the first group of not-space characters and all surrounding spaces - which would leave you w/ the numbers. However...

```
sed 's/ *[^ ]\{1,\} *//2' <infile
```

...would instead do the same to the second not-space group per line - which would leave you with just the names.